# How to add textarea field to taxonomy (tag)?

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy

How can I add custom field (textarea) to wordpress taxonomy (tag)?

```
add_action('admin_init', 'tag_custom_fields', 1);
if( !function_exists('tag_custom_fields') ) {
function tag_custom_fields()
    {
        add_action('edit_category_form_fields', 'tag_custom_fields_form');
        add_action('edited_category', 'tag_custom_fields_save');
        add_action( 'create_category', 'tag_custom_fields_save'); 
        add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'tag_custom_fields_form_new');

    }
}

if( !function_exists('tag_custom_fields_form') ) {
function tag_custom_fields_form($term)
    {
        $t_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
        wp_enqueue_script('wp-color-picker');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
?>
    <?php $settingseditor = array(
        'textarea_name' => 'description',
        'textarea_rows' => 10,
        'editor_class'  => 'i18n-multilingual',
    );

    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label><?php esc_html_e('Second tag description','framework'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <?php
            $meta_content = !empty($term_meta['tag_second_description']) ? $term_meta['tag_second_description'] : '';
            wp_editor( $meta_content, 'tag_second_description', array(
                    'wpautop' =>  true,
                    'media_buttons' => false,
                    'textarea_name' => 'term_meta[tag_second_description]',
                    'textarea_rows' => 10,
                    'teeny' =>  false
            ));
            ?>
            <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e('Set html for second category description (will be after posts)','framework'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>      
<?php
    }
}   



if( !function_exists('tag_custom_fields_form_new') ) {
function tag_custom_fields_form_new($term)
    {
        wp_enqueue_script('wp-color-picker');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
?>
        <div class="form-field">
            <label><?php esc_html_e('Second tag description','framework'); ?></label>
            <textarea name="term_meta[tag_second_description]" id=team_meta[tag_second_description]" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo (!empty($term_meta['tag_second_description'])) ? $term_meta['tag_second_description'] : ''; ?></textarea><br />
            <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e('Set html for second category description (will be after posts)','framework'); ?></span>
        </div>

<?php
    }    
}

if( !function_exists('tag_custom_fields_save') ) {    
function tag_custom_fields_save($term_id)
    {
        if (isset($_POST['term_meta'])) {
            $t_id = $term_id;
            $term_meta = get_option("taxonomy_$t_id");
            $cat_keys = array_keys($_POST['term_meta']);
            foreach ($cat_keys as $key) {
                if (isset($_POST['term_meta'][$key])) {
                    $term_meta[$key] = stripslashes($_POST['term_meta'][$key]);
                }
            }
            //save the option array
            update_option("taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code above but it adds a field to the category. I don't know how to make it add a field to the tag.

Comment: Did you look at this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/ instead of `edit_category_form_fields`